# Python request API transfer speeds are slower when data is collect to memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, asgi, hypercorn

While attempting to analyse the network transfer speeds using a hypercorn ASGI app and requests API, there is a significant drop in speed when the data is collected than otherwise.

**ASGI app**

```py
from typing import Any

ONE_KB = 1024
ONE_MB = ONE_KB * ONE_KB
ONE_GB = ONE_MB * ONE_KB

chunk_size = 256 * ONE_KB

dump = bytes(ONE_GB)  # 1GB


async def app(scope: Any, receive: Any, send: Any) -> None:
    '''
    Run: `hypercorn app:app --bind localhost:7001`
    '''
    assert scope["type"] == "http"

    await send(
        {
            "type": "http.response.start",
            "status": 200,
            "headers": [[b"Content-Type", b"application/octet-stream"], [b"Content-Length", str(len(dump)).encode()]],
        }
    )

    chunks = len(dump) // chunk_size

    for i in range(chunks):
        await send(
            {
                "type": "http.response.body",
                "body": dump[i * chunk_size : (i + 1) * chunk_size],
                "more_body": i != chunks - 1,
            }
        )
```

**test.py**

```py
import time
import requests

ONE_MB = 2**20

data_size_mb = 1000


async def test_speed():
    # Parse the URL to get host and path
    path = "/"

    print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info())
    load_mem = [b"a" * ONE_MB for _ in range(20 * 1000)] # << ==== This line doesn't impact the transfer speeds!
    print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info())

    start_time = time.time()

    # Create a TCP socket
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        # Connect to the server
        s.connect((host, port))

        # Send HTTP GET request
        request = f"GET {path} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {host}\r\n\r\n"
        s.sendall(request.encode())

        # Create a BufferedReader from the socket
        bufferedReader = io.BufferedReader(s.makefile("rb"))

        try:
            # Read response headers
            headers = bufferedReader.readline()
            while headers.strip():
                headers = bufferedReader.readline()
            bufferedReader.flush()

            # Receive response in chunks and write to file
            recv_size = 0
            chunks = []
            for _ in range(20 * 1000):
                data = bufferedReader.read(ONE_MB)
                chunks.append(data)  # <<< ===== This line is causing the above line to slow down !!!
                recv_size += len(data)
            psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info()
        finally:
            bufferedReader.close()

    recv_data_mb = recv_size / ONE_MB
    print("[*] Received data ", recv_size / ONE_MB, "MB")
    print("[*] Chunks size {}".format(str(len(chunks))))

    end_time = time.time()

    recv_time = end_time - start_time
    recv_speed = recv_data_mb / recv_time

    print("===========================================")
    print("Data size: {:.2f} MB".format(data_size_mb))
    print("Recv data size: {:.2f} MB".format(recv_data_mb))
    print("Recv time: {:.6f} seconds".format(recv_time))
    print("Recv speed: {:.2f} mbps".format(recv_speed))
    print("===========================================")
```

**Expectation:**
The transfer speed must be identical whether we collect the data into `chunks` variable or not.

**Actual:**
The transfer speed when `chunks.append(chunk)` is commented was around `2.6 gbps` and when it was NOT commented it reduced to `1.4 gbps`.

**EDIT #1:**

- The machine has over 1 TB of RAM and to check if its a memory issue I created a dummy list of size 20 GB before the response streaming and the transfer speed was 2.6 gbps. But if I create the list DURING the streaming and the speeds dropped to 1.4 gbps.
- Running cProfile for the two runs showed that for the faster run `(<method 'recv_into' of '_socket.socket' objects>)` was called by the BufferedReader almost `10 times` more leading me to suspect that the buffer size was changed for when I increase the memory during streaming.

**EDIT #2:**

- To close in on the bug, I'm now using sockets + buffered reader instead of request lib which is having the same behaviour.
- As pointed out by Steffen, I'm ensuring that actual physical memory is being used while.

**EDIT #3:**

- Adding line profiler outputs to highlight the slow down in `bufferedReader.read(..)` where the time taken almost doubled.

**Fast Run**

```bash
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    95         1          0.2      0.2      0.0          try:                                                                                                     
    96                                                       # Read response headers                                                                              
    97         1       1178.9   1178.9      0.0              headers = bufferedReader.readline()                                                                  
    98         7         14.1      2.0      0.0              while headers.strip():                                                                               
    99         6          3.8      0.6      0.0                  headers = bufferedReader.readline()                                                              
   100         1          3.9      3.9      0.0              bufferedReader.flush()                                                                               
   101                                                                                                                                                            
   102                                                       # Receive response in chunks and write to file                                                       
   103         1          0.8      0.8      0.0              recv_size = 0                                                                                        
   104         1          0.7      0.7      0.0              chunks = []                                                                                          
   105     20001       7028.7      0.4      0.0              for _ in range(20 * 1000):                                                                           
   106     20000    7692581.8    384.6     38.2                  data = bufferedReader.read(ONE_MB)                                                               
   107                                                           # chunks.append(data)  # <<< ===== This line is causing the above line to slow down !!!          
   108     20000      27589.1      1.4      0.1                  recv_size += len(data)
```

**Slow Run**

```bash
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    95         1          0.4      0.4      0.0          try:                                                                                                     
    96                                                       # Read response headers                                                                              
    97         1       1073.7   1073.7      0.0              headers = bufferedReader.readline()                                                                  
    98         7          7.8      1.1      0.0              while headers.strip():                                                                               
    99         6          3.7      0.6      0.0                  headers = bufferedReader.readline()                                                              
   100         1          1.5      1.5      0.0              bufferedReader.flush()                                                                               
   101                                                                                                                                                            
   102                                                       # Receive response in chunks and write to file                                                       
   103         1          0.2      0.2      0.0              recv_size = 0                                                                                        
   104         1          0.4      0.4      0.0              chunks = []                                                                                          
   105     20001       6652.0      0.3      0.0              for _ in range(20 * 1000):                                                                           
   106     20000   13057516.0    652.9     50.6                  data = bufferedReader.read(ONE_MB)                                                               
   107     20000      17805.7      0.9      0.1                  chunks.append(data)  # <<< ===== This line is causing the above line to slow down !!!            
   108     20000      22505.9      1.1      0.1                  recv_size += len(data)
```

**EDIT #4:**

- Based on Steffen's comment, I tried to not append the response from server but a random 1MB data to a list. Oddly enough the `bufferedReader.read()` were still high though the memory allocation is unrelated. But when I perform a `del data` at the end, the `bufferedReader.read()` speeds are down `50%`

Additionally just adding random 1 MB to `chunks` every iteration

```bash
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   106     20001       6580.4      0.3      0.0              for _ in range(20 * 1000):                                  
   107     20000   14320784.1    716.0     50.3                  data = bufferedReader.read(ONE_MB)                      
   108     20000      25183.2      1.3      0.1                  recv_size += len(data)                                  
   109     20000    1284105.9     64.2      4.5                  chunks.append(b"b" * ONE_MB)                            
   110                                                           # bufferedReader.flush()  # <<< ===== This line doesn't…
   111                                                           # chunks.append(copy(data))  # <<< ===== This line is c…
   112                                                           # del data  # <<< ===== Running this, improves the runt…
   113         1        470.7    470.7      0.0              psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info()
```

Adding random 1 MB to `chunks` and deleting `data` every iteration

```bash
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
106     20001       5896.1      0.3      0.0              for _ in range(20 * 1000):                                  
   107     20000    5089738.8    254.5     17.2                  data = bufferedReader.read(ONE_MB)                      
   108     20000      21017.8      1.1      0.1                  recv_size += len(data)                                  
   109     20000   12253592.9    612.7     41.3                  chunks.append(b"b" * ONE_MB)                            
   110                                                           # bufferedReader.flush()  # <<< ===== This line doesn't…
   111                                                           # chunks.append(copy(data))  # <<< ===== This line is c…
   112     20000      13553.3      0.7      0.0                  del data  # <<< ===== Running this, improves the runtim…
```

Comment: You are not measures the actual network transfer speed but the total time it takes for your code to receive the data. This includes everything your program does apart from transferring data, like allocating more and more memory. And memory allocation can be costly, and more so if the system is low on memory. When appending the `chunk` to `chunks` new memory must be allocated for the next receive, while without the previously allocated memory could be reused.

Comment: Is there a way to work around this overhead while getting speeds of 2.5 gbps?

Comment: If you insist on keeping everything in the memory then get more RAM and a faster CPU. Or use another programming language which allows you more fine control of how memory allocation is done, so that you can pre-allocate the full memory before reading. Python is simply not the right tool for high performance networking.

Comment: I went back and ensured that the machine has sufficient RAM & CPU in surplus for this scenario. I've edited the post with a test where I added 20 GB memory before the streaming logic and the speeds were high (2.6 gbps) but when I append to the list from within the streaming logic it dropped again.

Comment: `chunks = [bytes(ONE_MB) for _ in range(20 * 1000)]` does not actually allocate the memory from the hardware since everything is zero but it just reserves it from the OS. And it is therefore really quick. The actual memory gets only takes from the hardware on demand if something is written to it. Check rss vs. vms in `psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info()`

Comment: Thanks Steffen, I've updated it to use `[b"a" for _ in range(20 * 1000)]` and I'm still seeing the same behaviour. I've also opted to use sockets + bufferedreader since that's where the issue seems to reside when I debugged, and I'm able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `b"a"` allocates now only 1 bytes, instead of the 1MB you had before. So this can not be compared to the 1MB data chunks you read later.

Comment: Apologies, I copied the wrong code here. I tried again with `chunks = [b"a" * ONE_MB for _ in range(20 * 1000)]` and found the same behaviour.

Comment: OK, but do you understand that you cannot claim to be measuring throughput when your program is performing significant overhead tasks?  Benchmarking is a very tricky science.

Comment: Yup I agree. I just wanted to understand how the exactly overheads are manifested as part of this exercise. I still can't wrap my head around why `BufferedReader` would call `_socket.socket.readinto` far fewer times and that too only when I'm adding overhead to memory during the response streaming.

Comment: @Allen: Now you've moved the line which does the memory allocation out of computing the transfer speed. Surely it does not impact the transfer speed then anymore, because you don't measure it anymore. But the memory allocation for chunks is still measured, so it still impacts the transfer speed.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich To verify the same I ran a line profiler against this function and updated the question. I expected the time taken to increase inside the `for` loop against `chunks.append(data)`. But only the time against `data = bufferedReader.read(ONE_MB)` has increased. I'm trying to understand why memory allocation is impacting `BufferedReader.read`.

Comment: The memory underlying `chunk` is allocated inside `BufferedReader.read` Appending `chunk` to `chunks` is just adding the allocated buffer to the list, i.e. it is just changing ownership of the memory, not a copy. If this adding to `chunks` is not done the same memory buffer can be reused in the next `read`. But when the `chunk` was moved into `chunks` the underlying memory cannot be reused, so new memory needs to be allocated from the system when needed, which is inside `read`.

Comment: I attempted to replicate this & updated my findings in the question. First, I added a random 1MB bytes to chunks every iteration and found that still `bufferedReader.read(..)` has high runtimes which was very odd!! But when I ran `del data`, the `bufferedReader.read(..)` speeds went down and time for adding 1MB to chunks went up. This confirmed a few things but also raised a doubt. How is the memory for `data` and `chunks` related in the first experiment?